# How to plot data using custom objects in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I'm building an ArrayList that contains object of type "TimeRecord" (a object that I have defined). Each TimeRecord object contains the following fields:

- ID -> identifier of the field
- StartTime -> time when an object pass in a specific point of my network
- StopTime -> time when an object pass in another specific point of my network

Each time field is populated with the AnyLogic `time()` function and has the aim to collect the time between two point in my network. Is it possible to pass a list with the time differences `StopTime - StartTime` to a chart object to plot the the   time of every request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a dataset and update it using an event. For instance:

1. Drag a dataset to main (probably, to use a histogram dataset is a good idea in your case , it depends on what you want to show)
2. Drag an event to main to be updated every *n* times.
3. In the field action of the event you can add something like this:

`dataset.reset();
    for (TimeRecord t : YourArrayList) { 
      dataset.add(t.StopTime - t.StartTime); 
    }`

Another way to do this, without using a loop, it is to create a variable at the agent level to record start time, and then when the agent finishes what is doing add to the dataset the difference between stop and start.

Anyway, add a plot, and specify the corresponding dataset in the data field.